# can't find the error in my program

Tags: java, comparable

The first code block is in my main program in a static method.
In this main program, i set up the polygons and their areas are also found in a getArea() method which i later print out, but i'm using this setArea() method after printing the data to test the compareTo() method.
The second block is my overrided compareTo in my Polygon class implementing comparable.
**Why is setArea() method not updating the areas?**
Im thinking it might be a static problem, but not sure?

```
public static void printPolyData(){

    try{


        for(int i=0;i<=poly_count-1;i++){

        System.out.println("polygon #" + (i+1)); 
        System.out.println(poly_list.get(i).getSides() + " sides");
        System.out.println(poly_list.get(i).arrayToString());
        System.out.println("Area of Polygon = " + poly_list.get(i).getArea());
        System.out.println("Area of Polygon = " + poly_list.get(i).dListToString());


        }




                poly_list.get(0).setArea(0.00090);
                poly_list.get(1).setArea(0.00094);
                poly_list.get(2).setArea(0.000901);


                System.out.println("Comparing polygon0 (Area=" 
                + poly_list.get(0).getArea() + ") with polygon1 (Area=" 
                + poly_list.get(1).getArea() + ") : " +
                + poly_list.get(0).compareTo(poly_list.get(1)));

                System.out.println("Comparing polygon1 (Area=" 
                + poly_list.get(1).getArea() + ") with polygon0 (Area=" 
                + poly_list.get(0).getArea() + ") : " +
                + poly_list.get(1).compareTo(poly_list.get(0)));

                System.out.println("Comparing polygon0 (Area=" 
                + poly_list.get(0).getArea() + ") with polygon2 (Area=" 
                + poly_list.get(2).getArea() + ") : " +
                + poly_list.get(0).compareTo(poly_list.get(2)));


    }
    catch (Exception e){

        System.out.println("error printing polygon data. " + e.getMessage());

    }


}




 @Override
    public int compareTo(Polygon otherPoly) {



        double otherPolysArea = otherPoly.getArea(); 
        final double error = 0.00005;

        // otherPoly is bigger. current polygon smaller.
        if((this.getArea() - otherPolysArea) < -error){

            return -1;
        }
        // otherPoly is smaller. current polygon bigger.
        else if((this.getArea() - otherPolysArea) > error){

            return 1;
        }
        else{return 0;} // polygons are considered same.

    }

public void setArea(double area){


    this.area = area;

}
```

> Comparing polygon0 (Area=2.0) with polygon1 (Area=1.0) : 1 
>   Comparing polygon1 (Area=1.0) with polygon0 (Area=2.0) : -1 
>   Comparing Polygon0 (Area=2.0) with polygon2 (Area=1.5) : 1

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: FYI, When you pass in a parameter of type Polygon, you dont have to test for instanceOf

Comment: double otherPolysArea = ((Polygon) otherPoly).getArea(); //unneccessary cast.

Comment: Show the code for setArea.. Your CompareTo looks ok. But for my 2 comments

Comment: I added the setArea() method. also i apologise for the code from different classes not being in separate blocks im trying to format it as they tell me but its not cooperating.